# Detect the end of overscroll

Tags: javascript, ios

When an element has a `webkit-overflow-scrolling` set to "touch" (default for the `document.documentElement` on the iOS devices), then user can overscroll the content. When user releases the `touchevent`, it takes time until element is scrolled to 0.

How to detect the end of the overscroll?

Answer (score 2):

```
var overscroll;

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
    // User has very quick fingers.
    overscroll = false;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
    // User released touch-drag event when element was in an overscroll state.
    if (document.body.scrollTop < 0) {
        overscroll = true;
    }
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (overscroll && document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
        overscroll = false;

        console.log('end of overscroll');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this may only work for top-overscroll.  On iOS Safari, anyways, `body.scrollTop` is positive for overscroll bottom.  I used this logic to detect bottom overscroll: `const isOverscrolledBottom = body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight > body.scrollHeight`